# How to troubleshoot Sitecore slow performance on the CMS?

Tags: performance, content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore7.2

Our Sitecore 7.2 website runs quite fast, the problem starts when we want to change a lot of items on the backend. Even just **opening** an item takes 5-6 seconds, and saving the same.

I have events handler for when an item is created or renamed, but no more - I can't fathom why clicking on an item and seeing its details takes so much time. Does the debug mode works for the backend too? How can I start figuring out where the bottleneck is?

Comment: Which Sitecore version are you on?

Comment: Sitecore 7.2 - should have mentioned that, sorry. Editing the question now.

Comment: If you have 64bit environment, try to set Caching.DisableCacheSizeLimits to "true"

Comment: When you say "change a lot of items", how many items are you changing? Are you importing data into Sitecore?

Comment: Hi golden grahams, I mean the day-to-day going through items in the CMS and changing properties.
I need a way of finding out what the system is doing during those long seconds, so that I can add indexes / pre-fetch / cache as needed.

Comment: Ahmed, thank you for your suggestion but I'd rather learn what causes the problem and then find a solution for it - I just need the right tools to investigate this performance issue.

Comment: 7.2 has a bug (or feature, I've yet to determine). So just to get us going, try this. Add a setting to your Sitecore settings: "ItemCloning.Enabled" with value "false". It should give you a VERY noticeable difference.

Comment: So under Sitecore.config, under <settings>, I add <setting name="ItemCloning.Enabled" value="false" />?

Comment: @EmanueleCiriachi My suggestion was to see if this config change will improve the performance, as this might indicate that your cache size settings are not enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To troubleshoot performance issues in Sitecore (including the content editor) your best bet is to start with the [CMS Performance Tuning Guide](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%207/CMS%20Performance%20Tuning%20Guide.aspx).
There's a companion to it, the [CMS Diagnostics Guide](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%207/CMS%20Diagnostics%20Guide.aspx).

Depending on what you find, you may need to read up on indexing, caching, browser configuration - again, lots of the information is on SDN.

For the content editor, for instance, there are some application settings that can make a huge difference to loading items - e.g. Prefetch collapsed sections, show fields from standard templates, which warnings you show in the gutter.

The [Sitecore Log Analyzer](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Log_Analyzer.aspx) will almost certainly be very useful to you, if you add some performance counters to the log (though these can themselves impact performance).

You can also monitor caches at the admin/cache.aspx - if your cache deltas go haywire or cache sizes reach maximums then you'll have a performance hit

But I'd start by simply monitoring your server resources while you perform one of your troublesome item updates - that should at least let you know if your bottleneck is memory, CPU, SQL connectivity etc.

Comment: Thank you, will go through it at some point during the next week. Will definitely come back with feedback, although it won't be instantaneous!

Comment: It's very tricky to find out whether a performance issue is configuration, hardware or code related and at what level. Good luck!

Comment: +1 to the tuning guide... lots of good tips there. Having a weekly SQL Server maintenance plan is one of the most important. Fragmented indexes can make the CM server *very* slow.

Answer (score 0):

As time goes, not only Sitecore framework, but any other technology, hardware evolves over time.

The end advice/solution that was actual a while ago might not be applicable today.

It is far more important to be capable of finding reasons in exact **your** solution why certain operation is slow.

[No random changes](http://www.brendangregg.com/methodology.html), every change has to be based on facts. Wall clock response times are to be investigated by performance profiles:

- [Introduction to wall clock investigation](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/PerfView-Tutorial/Tutorial-12-Wall-Clock-Time-Investigation-Basics)
- [Wall clock investigations in ASP.NET](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/PerfView-Tutorial/Tutorial-14-Investigating-Wall-Clock-responce-time-in-ASPNET-Scenarios)
- [Collecting PerfView profiles in Sitecore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKZFEpy8sJ0)
- [Analyzing Sitecore PerfView profile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJGUaXoz6LA)

Here is a blog dedicated to [Sitecore performance investigations](https://making-it-faster.blog/) with real life case studies.